# Annote and count posts related to a specific class, in Django

Tags: python, django, count, annotations, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following three classes; Topic, Entry and Comment, and I whish to annote and count the number of entries (objects in class Entry) in each Topic post.

```
class Topic(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   topic_count = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Entry(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   entry = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   belongsTo = models.ForeignKey(Topic)

class Comment(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   comment_count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   belongsTo = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
```

I've tried to annote with;

```
entry_count = Topic.objects.values('title').annotate(entry_count = Count('id')).order_by('-entry_count')
```

which returns a list with some of the entries;

```
[{'entry_count': 1, 'title': u'Topic1'}, {'entry_count': 1, 'title': u'Topic2'}, {'entry_count': 1, 'title': u'Topic3'}]
```

I'm trying to get the following; there are three posts in Topic one so entry_count for Topic1 would be 3,  there are two entry -posts in Topic2 so the entry_count for Topic2 would be 2.

Comment: Try this - `Topic.objects.annotate(entry_count=Count('entry'))`. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

```
entry_count = Topic.objects.values('title').annotate(Count('entry')).order_by('-entry__count')
```

Answer (score 0):

`entry_count = Topic.objects.annotate(entry_count=Count('entry'))`